# What happened to Suru icon designs?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, icons, design

A long time ago some images emerged presenting the Suru icon designs for files and folders.

Those images can be viewed here:

[image: suru folders design]
[image: suru icon designs]

Is it known what happened with that beautiful designs? Are they under development and heading to Unity 8 someday or they were abandoned? For some reason Ubuntu Phone's file manager uses the Humanity icons, not those presented.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update on December, 2017

It seems the icon theme development has resumed under a new leader [Sam Hewitt](https://github.com/snwh/suru-icon-theme) (the lead designer of Moka, Paper and some more beautiful icon sets)

Here is the github repo where new development is happening  https://github.com/snwh/suru-icon-theme

---

#### (Original Answer)

> Are they under development and heading to Unity 8 someday or they were abandoned?

It seems, Yes, Suru icon theme is still under development. These are under ubuntu-theme project name. You can view the project page from launchpad here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-themes. There are several bug fixings in 2016 as I can see. The binary packages it produces include `suru-icon-theme`. You can even install it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install suru-icon-theme
```

So, I believe they are not abandoned.

To answer, *will they land in Unity 8?* is very hard. Even Michael Hall ([A Canonical worker](http://mhall119.com/about/)) said in a [blog post of May 2016](http://mhall119.com/2016/05/dogfooding-unity-8/), he don't know about them replying one of the reader's question (I guess, it was you who asked the question there). He said (quoting)

> Question: A few years ago some of the Suru icons has been shown – including folder icons, filetype icon etc. They were beautiful. Will they ever land?
>
> > Answer: I don’t know, do you have any links to those icons?

You also said

> For some reason Ubuntu Phone's file manager uses the Humanity icons, not those presented.

It could be probably the design haven't been yet implemented. Your posted images were just designs.

Comment: Yes, those comments are mine indeed.I intended to rise this question again now with hope someone else might have more information on that.

The images I posted are the designs indeed, just I would like to know if it is under development or abandoned at all.

I downloaded and browsed the suru-icon-theme package a few days ago. So far it contains only symbolic icons and application icons - neither mimetypes nor the new folder icons are there.

Comment: @Mitu suru uses defualt icons as fallback and replaces some icons in default. I think it is because the development isn't complete yet. it also possible that the project is abandoned. However I couldn't find any evidence of that . Again, if a canonical employee can't answer this, I think your hope to get exact answer from AU is low. Unless Mark shuttleworth answers this

Comment: It is low, you're right. Anyone from the design team might know something, but they may not want to share now. Anyway, I keep fingers crossed for these icons and the rest of the Suru theme.

Comment: @Mitu Mark shuttlework has an account here and sometimes he answers.

Comment: @Mitu I've found some updated info about Suru. Check the answer